# How do you debug typelevel code?

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

Most of the time, all you get is an implicit not found error. You don't know where in the chain of implicit construction it failed. Apparently you can't use runtime debug or print statement. So how do you debug type-level program other than staring at your code really hard?

Comment: EPFL, Typesafe, and the Scala team currently have multiple research positions open to answer that exact question. Or, in other words: the answer to that question is worth a PhD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish I had a better answer, but here it goes: Start passing the parameters explicitly, one at a time until it gives you a more useful error. (adding-prinlns-equivalent for implicits params)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `???` for undefined code parts (because it have bottom type `Nothing`) and `_` for unknown types. Also see `-Ytyper-debug` compiler option (more options here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html). According to problem with implicit parameters and wrappers, "Idea" has nice feature "Show Implicit Hints" and "Implicit Arguments" (`Main menu > Help > Find Action...` and type e.g. *implicit*). Also, you can use `Null` bottom type instance `null` for AnyRef like `null: YourTypeHere`.