# How to debug type-level programs

Tags: debugging, haskell, types

I'm trying to do some hoopy type-level programming, and it just doesn't work. I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out why the heck GHC utterly fails to infer the type signatures I want.

Is there some way to make GHC *tell me* what it's doing?

I tried `-ddump-tc`, which just prints out the final type signatures. (Yes, they're wrong. Thanks, I already knew that.)

I also tried `-ddump-tc-trace`, which dumps out ~70KB of unintelligible gibberish. (In particular, I can't see any user-written identifiers mentioned *anywhere*.)

My code is *so close* to working, but somehow an extra type variable keeps appearing. For some reason, GHC can't see that this variable should be completely determined. Indeed, if I *manually* write the five-mile type signature, GHC happily accepts it. So I'm clearly just missing a constraint somewhere... *but where?!?* >_<

Comment: You should post at least some code. As far as I know, type-level programs are best debugged with `:kind!`, holes and `Any` as type-level hole.

Comment: The code I have is large and complicated, and I doubt anybody will be able to follow it. What I'm asking for is tips on how to hunt down where the problem is, so I know where to start looking.

Comment: This comment is just to potentially enable me to say 'called it!' later: are you assuming some type family is injective?

Comment: @Cactus LOL! I've got GADTs, existential quantification, rank-N types and overlapping instances... but no type families.

Comment: Hey, it was worth a shot :)

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Answer is here already answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/34754070/4620369

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you debug typelevel code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753708/how-do-you-debug-typelevel-code)

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, poking around with :kind and :kind! in GHCi is usually how I go about doing it, but it also surprisingly matters where you place the functions, and what looks like it should be the same, isn't always.

For instance, I was trying to make a dependently typed functor equivalent, for a personal project, which looked like

```
class IFunctor f where 
  ifmap :: (a -> b) -> f n a -> f n b
```

and I was writing the instance for

```
data IEither a n b where 
  ILeft :: a -> IEither a Z b 
  IRight :: b -> IEither a (S n) b
```

It should be fairly simple, I thought, just ignore f for the left case, apply it in the right.

I tried

```
instance IFunctor (IEither a) where
  ifmap _ l@(ILeft _) = l 
  ifmap f (IRight r) = IRight $ f r
```

but for the specialized version of ifmap in this case being `ifmap :: (b -> c) -> IEither a Z b -> IEither a Z c`, Haskell inferred the type of l to be `IEither a Z b` on the LHS, which, makes sense, but then refused to produce `b ~ c`.

So, I had to unwrap l, get the value of type a, then rewrap it to get the `IEither a Z c`.

This isn't just the case with dependent types, but also with rank-n types.
For instance, I was trying to convert isomorphisms of a proper form into natural transformations, which should be fairly easy, I thought.

Apparently, I had to put the deconstructors in a where clause of the function, because otherwise type inference didn't work properly.