# Type signature is too general; missing constraint?

Tags: haskell, types

So I tried to ask a general "[how do you debug type-level programming problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101800/how-to-debug-type-level-programs)" question, and it seems either the question is too general to answer, or maybe it's impossible to debug such things. :-}

On this particular day, the problem that's irking me is a moderately large, complex program. I've managed to boil it down to a reasonably small core that still goes wrong. Here we go:

```
{-#
  LANGUAGE
    GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses,
    FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, RankNTypes,
    KindSignatures
#-}

module Minimal where

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data Union (t :: * -> *) (ts :: * -> *) x

class Member (x :: * -> *) (ys :: * -> *) where
instance Member x (Union x ys) where
instance (Member x ys) => Member x (Union y ys) where

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data ActM (effects :: * -> *) x
instance Monad (ActM effects) where

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data Reader i x where
  Get :: Reader i i

get :: Member (Reader i) req => ActM req i
get = undefined

runReader :: i -> ActM (Union (Reader i) req) x -> ActM req x
runReader = undefined
```

(Aside: I look at that list of language extensions and think to myself "maybe this is just a terrible idea!")

Anyway, the really interesting part is at the bottom. We see that

```
runReader :: i -> ActM (Union (Reader i) req) x -> ActM req x
```

In other words, for any `i`, `runReader` takes an action in the `ActM` monad that has `Reader i` as one of its possible effects, and returns an action in the `ActM` monad *without* that possible effect. Simple, right?

Now if I pass (say) a `Char` as the first argument, then the reader type is fixed to `Char`:

```
runReader 'X' :: ActM (Union (Reader Char) req) x -> ActM req x
```

So far, so good. If I just return some data, all is fine:

```
runReader 'X' (return True) :: ActM req Bool
```

(Reassuringly, I also get the correct *value* as the result!)

But now, what about the `get` function?

```
get :: Member (Reader i) req => ActM req i
```

So `get` is an action in the `ActM` monad for any set of effects that includes `Reader i`. And that means that if I pass it to `runReader` then I get...

```
runReader 'X' get :: Member (Reader x) (Union (Reader Char) req) => ActM req x
```

...wait, what?!? Why hasn't the compiler figured out that `x` *must* be `Char`?

Indeed, if I add an explicit type signature that says

```
runReader 'X' get :: ActM req Char
```

then it compiles perfectly (and, incidentally, I get the right value output, which is nice). So where am I missing a constraint?

Comment: The instance `Member x (Union x ys)` requires that both the `x`s be the same to begin with to match - the compiler will not deduce this information. You would have to write `(x ~ x') => Member x (Union x' xs)` but this would be overlapping with the other instance - I believe you need a cleverer way of computing membership.

Comment: Is that really enough extensions? Those two `Member` instances look awfully suspicious -- like maybe you'll need `OverlappingInstances` or perhaps even `IncoherentInstances` for those to "work". If you've got `IncoherentInstances` on, well... I think the official party line with that extension is, "Good luck, don't complain to us.".

Comment: @DanielWagner That's odd... `OverlappingInstances` is supposed to be in there. I'm not sure how it ended up missing. I must have accidentally dropped it while building my minimal example.

Comment: @user2407038 I was surprised to learn that you can actually write `x ~ y` in a type signature! You learn something new every day...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler hasn't figured out that `x` must be `Char` because it isn't true. For example, one might write

```
type ReadsBool req = Union (Reader Bool) req
type ReadsCharAndBool req = Union (Reader Char) (ReadsBool req)
```

and then you have:

```
runReader 'X' (get :: ReadsCharAndBool req) :: ActM (ReadsBool req) Bool
```

So congratulations, now you know why [mtl's `MonadReader` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader-Class.html#t:MonadReader) has the fundep it does: for type inference reasons, one often wants the monad to uniquely determine what kind of thing you can `get` from it.

Comment: So where exactly are you suggesting I need a fundep?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid There is no small change to your code that comes to mind that would fix things. Everything I can thing of is more of a sweeping architectural change. Your `Member` typeclass is "bad" from a type inference point of view: the `Member x (Union y ys)` instance can _always_ match; and worse matching tells you almost nothing about the types `x`, `y`, or `ys`, because the open world assumption says anybody can come along later and add a `Member x ys` instance for any stupid pair of types! You could consider splitting it into a `ReaderMember` class (and similar for other effects).